# How to know which button redirected to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exmaple</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Example Send<h2>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Button1</button>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Button2</button>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Button3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

All buttons redirects to the same page. What I want is on the redirected page (main.html) know which button number was pressed and then show information about it (in this example changing the conten of the h1).
The main.html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Receiver</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Button number <span id="data"> 'The number of button should go here'</span> was clicked<h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The real application will be executed on a page where different devices are presented as cards, when the button "info" is pressed of one card I need to redirect to the dashboard page that will receive the mac adrress corresponding to the device selected and will display th database information from that device in some charts.

I think I should use javascript to do this, but I am stuck in how can I communicate betwen two scripts executed by differents html.
thanks.

Comment: Use something like ```location.href = 'main.html?btn=button1'```

Comment: And how can I read it later (in the main.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your redirect location and add a unique search query for each button.

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'main.html?btn=button1';">Button1</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="location.href = 'main.html?btn=button2';">Button2</button>
<hr>
<button onclick="location.href = 'main.html?btn=button3';">Button3</button>
```

And `main.html` write a script and read the query string value by using `URLSearchParams`

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const btnValue = urlParams.get('btn');
```

**Note:** `URLSearchParams` has no support for IE.